# Cannot access repositories on R (in Ubuntu), except for attemps on "vanilla" session

Tags: r, package, repository, cran

I have reproduced this error in R versions 3.2.3 and 3.4.4; running both through terminal or within RStudio GUI. My OS is `Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS`. The problem started this week.
I found that the problem does not occur on a `R --vanilla` session.

When I start R, I get this message:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/contrib:   no fue posible abrir la URL 'http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

Next, when I try to install a package I get:

```
Warning in install.packages :

cannot open URL 'http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/contrib:
  no fue posible abrir la URL 'http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

My session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_AR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_AR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3
```

The current repository is (but I have already tried with several repositories):

```
getOption("repos")
                              CRAN 
"http://www.vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: inline code makes text more readable. Also, no need to write your name

Comment: Have you tried to use any other repositories? You can do this by specifying the CRAN repo in the `install.packages` command. e.g. `install.packages("package", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Comment: Yes, I have tried using several other repositories

Comment: Are you only choosing "http" vs "https" CRAN repos? But you are getting that message when you start R and not when you run `install.packages()`? Do you have an .RProfile script that's run when you start R? Is there code there?

Comment: @MrFlick I tried with both http and https CRAN repos. I get the message both when I start R and when I run `install.packages()`. In the file Rprofile.site there is no code (only commented instructions).